# How to convert stream results to string

Tags: java, dom, filestream

I want to convert the stream result output to string since I want 
to use it in Junit I think that I need to use the string writer but
Im not sure how exactly to use it.

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Thanks
Fedor

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at and learn to use the javadocs of the StreamResult class (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/). 
One of the constructors of StreamResult takes a Writer object as a parameter. You will see that one of the sub-classes of Writer is StringWriter. So to obtain a string from what is written to the StreamResult, you can construct a StringWriter, put it into the StreamResult, transform() the Source to the StreamResult and get the string from the StringWriter.

```
//create a StringWriter for the output
StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult( outWriter );
...
transformer.transform( source, result );  
StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer(); 
String finalstring = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Hello Timo,Thanks but where should I put the converter StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

Comment: Well, you either put the result into a file using StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml")); or you put it into a StringWriter using StreamResult result = new StreamResult( outWriter ); Why using a file if you want it in a string?

Comment: what is 'source' representing?

Comment: I'd guess that `source` is the XML that is getting transformed.

Answer (score 32):

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));
String output = writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) in this way :

```
StringWriter sw = (StringWriter) result.getWriter(); 
StringBuffer sb = sw.getBuffer(); 
String finalstring = sb.toString();
```

Comment: this is the one i was looking for

Comment: What is the difference between using a buffer or not, like in @nosid answer?